# How to play animation of scn model

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

How can I play animation, which is already in my .scn model? When I check it in model inspector, I can play it but how to play it in code?Do I need to have the model in .dae format to play the animation?

Comment: https://blog.pusher.com/animating-3d-model-ar-arkit-mixamo/

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thanks, but this with a .scn model does not work

Comment: Did you fine a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I bought a 3D model online in .blend format. Baked the actions and exported it as a .dae file (with animation like yours). In Xcode when you click on the .scn file, it has two "parts" one is the 3D model, the other the animation. I dragged the animation part onto the model and it merged in the hierarchy. After that I projected the 3D model just like a static 3D model and it was animated automatically. Sorry my terminology is bad as I am new too. Hope this helps!

Comment: I had a look at Xcode, the part where the animation and 3D model is located is under "scene graph". That's where I merged them.